# Wire winding modelling

Tags: modeling, animation

I am an absolute beginner in Blender and was wondering if it is possible to model a wire winding like the one in the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nEpt_ofrBZg
I have installed the Blender version 2.80, and it seems to me, the problem would not be so easy.

Could anybody give some idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116608/how-to-make-a-rope-winding-animation?r=SearchResults&s=2|50.4327   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183182/animating-wire-cable-rope-wrapping-around-a-cylinder   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76756/animate-winding-a-ribbon-rope-cable-around-a-cylinder  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139610/unwinding-spool-of-rope?r=SearchResults&s=1|49.7352  maybe  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86385/how-to-get-the-physics-engine-to-wraps-a-string-around-the-moving-part-of-a-moto

Comment: Thanks @batFINGER . I'll take the last link to try to model what I want. When it is complete, I will upload it here.